# Why "ist gestoppt" but not "ist aufgehört"

Tags: verb-usage

Although the auxiliary verb for stoppen is haben, I see many examples of the use of "gestoppt sein":

> Stimmengewirr Der Bau ist gestoppt.

> Diegeler macht eine kurze Armbewegung, und das Blut ist gestoppt.

but I can find no examples of "aufgehört sein". It is always "aufgehört haben".

> Die Blutung hat aufgehört.

Is there a fundamental reason for this or is it accounted for simply by convention?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Stoppen" is a transitive verb, and thus, it can also be used in passive voice:

> Die Behörde hat den Bau gestoppt.
> Der Bau wurde von der Behörde gestoppt.
> Der Bau ist gestoppt. *(Zustandspassiv)*

"Aufhören" an intransitive verb, it can't be used with an accusative object. In standard German, one can only say *"mit etwas aufhören"* or *"damit aufhören, etwas zu tun"*. That's why the verb *aufhören* can't be used in passive voice or Zustandspassiv in the same way, where the object becomes the subject.

> Die Arbeiter haben mit dem Bauen aufgehört.
> Die Arbeiter haben aufgehört, die Straße zu bauen.

You might sometimes find a sloppy use of transitive *aufhören* ("Sie hat das Rauchen aufgehört."), but it's not correct in standard German and does sound wrong.

Addition: As Janka remarked in the comments, intransitive verbs can still have a passive voice, but without an actual subject, and in most cases, Zustandspassiv isn't used.

> Es wurde von den Arbeitern mit dem Bauen aufgehört.
> Von den Arbeitern wurde mit dem Bauen aufgehört.

There are a few intransitive verbs that are also used with a Zustandspassiv, but imo these are exceptions with their own established meaning.

> Mir ist damit nicht geholfen.

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't argue with intransitivity and neither with passive voice because even truly intransitive verbs may have a passive voice in German: e.g *Ihm wird damit geholfen.* and also *Ihm **ist** damit geholfen.* — *Aufhören* is special because it allows neither an accusative nor a dative object. But you can still say *Es wird damit aufgehört.*

Comment: @Janka: thanks, you're right, I have edited the simplification and added some explanations.